# how to hide UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator that I would like to remove in an if statment.. but I dont know the code for removing the UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator...

If someone could tell me what to write that would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try setting the `accessoryType` to be `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`

Write the below code under `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Hope this helps.